# Which Order of the Phoenix members use the name Voldemort?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, order-of-the-phoenix

We know that some OOTP members use the name Voldemort:

> “Exactly! You’ve got to give them credit, it makes sense. It was only people who were serious about standing up to him, like Dumbledore, who ever dared use it. Now they’ve put a Taboo on it, anyone who says it is trackable — **quick-and-easy way to find Order members**!

Yet we see that not all of them do, for example Professor McGonagall:

> ‘My dear Professor, surely a sensible person like yourself can call him by his name? All this “You-Know-Who” nonsense – for eleven years I have been trying to persuade people to call him by his proper name: Voldemort.’
>
> Professor McGonagall flinched, but Dumbledore, who was unsticking two sherbet lemons, seemed not to notice.
>
> ‘It all gets so confusing if we keep saying “You-Know-Who”.’ I have never seen any reason to be frightened of saying Voldemort’s name.’

In the books, which Order of The Phoenix members use the name and which don't?

Comment: Your second quote is from book 1, right? Lots of people lose their fear of saying the name over time, such as Hermione and I think Lupin.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I know. Interesting that in the first wizarding war they were too scared to though Dumbledore was persuading everyone he knew.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Quite a few Order members use the name.

**Albus Dumbledore**

> “Call him **Voldemort**, Harry. Always use the proper name for things. Fear of a name increases fear of the thing itself.”
>   <sub>*(Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 17, The Man With Two Faces)*.</sub>

**Rubeus Hagrid**

> “Could you write it down?” Harry suggested.
>   “Nah - can’t spell it. All right - **Voldemort**.” Hagrid shuddered.
>   <sub>*(Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 4, The Keeper of the Keys)*.</sub>

**Sirius Black**

> Black started to laugh, a horrible, mirthless laugh that filled the whole room.
>   “**Voldemort**, teach me tricks?” he said.
>   <sub>*(Prisoner of Azkaban, Chapter 19, The Servant of Lord Voldemort)*.</sub>

**Mad-Eye Moody**

> “That’s Dumbledore’s brother, Aberforth, only time I ever met him, strange bloke...That’s Dorcas Meadowes, **Voldemort** killed her personally...Sirius, when he still had short hair...and...there you go, thought that would interest you!”
>   <sub>*(Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 9, The Woes of Mrs Weasley)*.</sub>

**Hestia Jones**

> “Doesn’t matter?” repeated Hestia, her voice rising ominously. “Don’t these people realise what you’ve been through? What danger you are in? The unique position you hold in the hearts of the anti-**Voldemort** movement?”
>   <sub>*(Deathly Hallows, Chapter 3, The Dursleys Departing)*.</sub>

**Remus Lupin**

> “I’m sorry, Harry, but I had to check,” said Lupin tersely. “We’ve been betrayed. **Voldemort** knew that you were being moved tonight and the only people who could have told him were directly involved in the plan. You might have been an impostor.”
>   <sub>*(Deathly Hallows, Chapter 5, Fallen Warrior)*.</sub>

**Bill Weasley**

> “We saw it,” said Bill; Fleur nodded, tear tracks glittering on her cheeks in the light from the kitchen window. “It happened just after we broke out of the circle: Mad-Eye and Dung were close by us, they were heading north too. **Voldemort** - he can fly - went straight for them.
>   <sub>*(Deathly Hallows, Chapter 5, Fallen Warrior)*.</sub>

That's enough to surmise that most Order members would be comfortable using the name and that people like Minerva McGonagall and Severus Snape were the exception.

We don't have evidence for all the Order members. Other characters either don't use the name or we don't have enough information to say.

Comment: Pretty good answer, but I wanted a full list. I.e, which do and which don't. And a one time use is meaningless, hence Hagrid would fall under the catagory of non-sayers.

Comment: @TheAsh This is a complete list of everyone in the Order who uses the name. The others either don't or there's insufficient evidence to say. If you want a full list of all the times people refer to Voldemort and the terms they use then that would be too long for a single answer.

Comment: "The others either don't or there's insufficient evidence to say." Thanks. I didn't know that from your answer. I accepted your answer, do you mind adding that quote to it at the end?

Comment: Hagrid used the name just once so I don't think he qualifies. In book six or something, he tells Harry to stop saying that name. I think Kingsley also used the name. That's how he was cornered in Book seven.